# WPF: set log level and refresh collection after changing

Tags: wpf, collections

So I have form that show my `Application` `Log`.

This is my `Log` model:

```
public class LogEntry : IComparable<LogEntry>
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public Level Level { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(LogEntry other)
    {
        return DateTime.CompareTo(other.DateTime);
    }
}

public enum Level
{
    All = 0,
    Debug,
    Info,
    Warn,
    Error,
    Fatal,
    Off
}
```

**Log Helper**

This is my `LogHelper` class that add the current `LogEvent` according the level that the user selected:

```
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static ObservableCollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public static bool AddLogToList { get; set; }
    private static int _level;
    private static int _index;
    private static string _formatPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff";

    public static void SetLevel(Level level)
    {
        _level = (int)level;
    }

    public static void AddLog(Level level, string message, string className, string methodName)
    {
        if (LogEntries == null)
            LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntry>();

        if (AddLogToList)
        {
            int levelValue = (int)level;
            if (levelValue >= _level)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    if (LogEntries.Count == 1000)
                        LogEntries.RemoveAt(LogEntries.Count - 1);

                    LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry()
                    {
                        DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(_formatPattern),
                        Index = _index++,
                        Level = level,
                        Source = className + "\\" + methodName,
                        Message = message.Trim()
                    };

                    LogEntries.Insert(0, logEntry);
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I am add `LogEvent` into my list that contains up ti `1000` entries.

Now I want to be able to filter and show my only the relevant `LogEvent` Level.

So I added `ComboBox` with all my `LogEvent` levels and subscribe to its `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void cbLogLevel_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = cbLogLevel.SelectedIndex;
    LogHelper.SetLevel((Level)index);
    lvLogger.ItemsSource = LogHelper.LogEntries.Where(m => m.Level == (Level)index).ToList();
}
```

So after this `SelectionChanged` event I can see the relevant `LogEvent` level but my only issue is the new `LogEvent` not shows.

Maybe I need kind of refresh to my collection or something else ?

Comment: I suggest you investigate listcollectionview and filtering. Base a listcollectionview on your observablecollection and add a filter which compares the levels of the item and your selected level. Filter can be set as a predicate. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26673.wpf-collectionview-tips.aspx#Filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `List<LogEntry>` and setting the `ItemsSource` property to this one in your event handler. This means that `lvLogger` will no longer be connected to the `ObservableCollection`.

Instead of resetting the `ItemsSource`, you could filter the view:

```
private void cbLogLevel_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = cbLogLevel.SelectedIndex;
    Level level = (Level)index;

    LogHelper.SetLevel(level);

    var collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvLogger.ItemsSource);
    collectionView.Filter = x =>
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = x as LogEntry;
        return logEntry != null && logEntry.Level == level;
    };
}
```